# Запретить переход к элементу HTML

Tags: jquery, javascript

На странице есть ссылка: `<a href="#tab">Profile</a>`

И невидимый блок: `<div id="tab"></div>`

Как в JS сделать, чтобы по клику на ссылку сначала проверялось некое условие и лишь потом отображался блок? Или просто запретить переход

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложность-то в чем? Используйте **return false;** или **preventDefault()** (отменяет действие по умолчанию)

```
$(function(){
  var val = 110;
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
    if(val != 100){
      // отменяем переход или не выполняем какое-либо действие.
      e.preventDefault();
      // или
      return false;
    } else {
        // выполняем какое-то действие
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: В моем случае нет условия. Необходимо просто заблокировать переход по элементу

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, значит без условия, а просто блокируйте. Я вам показал как. И про условие не я придумал:

> ...сначала проверялось некое условие...